# Index error while trying to send message telegram bot

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, telegram-bot

In my code, I want to send a number of strings inside a list to some users with specific chat_id and I am using 1 for loop and Im getting Index Error because my chat_id list has less elements than the string list.

```
        def sendTextMessage(self):
        for i in range(len(self.chat_id) + 10):
            link = random.choices(importinks())
            url = 'https://api.telegram.org/botMY_BOT_TOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id={}&text={}'.format(self.chat_id[i],link)
            r = requests.get(url)
            time.sleep(2)
            print(r.status_code)
            print(self.chat_id)
```

Can someone please explain to me how to fix this without using nested for-loops?

Comment: What's chat_id, and why are you adding 10 to it?

Comment: the reason I'm adding 10 is that the amount of link that is being sent is equal to the number of chat_id list elements and I want to send more links.

Comment: @Phix dude, I'm really stuck on this problem. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send, as you say, 15 random messages to each user id, you should use a loop like the one below:

```
for id in self.chat_id:    
    for i in range(15):
            link = random.choices(importinks())
            url = 'https://api.telegram.org/botMY_BOT_TOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id={}&text={}'.format(id,link)
            r = requests.get(url)
            time.sleep(2)
            print(r.status_code)
            print(self.chat_id)
```

I'm not sure what to do about your time issues except to lower the number of random links you're sending.

Comment: I know that but the number of links being sent is equal to the number of elements inside self.chat_id and I want to send more links. Do you know what should I do?

Comment: What self.chat_id[i] value do you want to use for those additional ones? Perhaps you can just add second loop after this one for all the additional links you want to push?

Comment: well, the problem is that there is not enough item in self.chat_id. I have 4 ID in my chat_it list and I want to send about 15 links so there is no proper value for the additionals and using nested loops takes much time to run. If you want I can give you my whole code.

Comment: Well run this for me - after the first 4 chat_id's, what do you want the url to be for the 5th link?  Explain that and it may be easier.

Comment: Let me make it clear. I have 4 chat_it which I should send 15 links to each of them. I am using a for loop to do it. maybe the problem is with the random.choices but Im not sure. I'll send the whole program to you at chat message. Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer so that it more closely reflects what you want.  Your timing issues are going to be hard to get around unless you want to just send fewer links to each user_id, but you'll be sending 60 links no matter whether you structure it as a nested loop or you use some other method.

Comment: Thanks for your response but a nested loop takes much much time to run and not that efficient. Do you know anything else rather than nested for loops?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210269/discussion-between-katardin-and-taha-jalili-tati).